# Note: com.google.common.cache.Striped64 accesses a declared field 'base' dynamically

Tags: java, android, android-studio, proguard, android-proguard

I am using ProGuard with my Android Studio Project. When I build my release I get the following note:

```
Note: com.google.common.cache.Striped64 accesses a declared field 'base' dynamically
      Maybe this is program field 'com.google.common.cache.Striped64 { long base; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'org.jsoup.nodes.Entities { java.util.Map base; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'org.jsoup.nodes.Entities$EscapeMode { org.jsoup.nodes.Entities$EscapeMode base; }'
```

I tried to solve it with:

```
-keep class org.jsoup.** { *; }
-keeppackagenames org.jsoup.nodes
-keep class com.google.common.cache.Striped64 { *; }
-keep class com.google.common.base.** { *; }
```

but it did not help.

**How do I resolve this Note?**

Answer (score 5):

To fix this you have to provide the following to your proguard configuration:

```
-keepclassmembers class ** {
  ** base;
}
```

This simply means do not rename all members named "base" of any type in any class.

Works like a charm.